# gvim popup menu item only in Nerdtree window

Tags: vim, menu, popup, nerdtree

I have a following menu item

```
nnoremenu 1.120 PopUp.Add\ &To\ &&Path          :call NERDTreeAddNodeToPath()<CR>
```

but I want it to show only in Nerdtree window, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've cracked this, but it's not as pretty as I had hoped. I have written a function `NERDTreeMenuToggle()` which adds the line to the popup menu if the current buffer is filetype "nerdtree", otherwise the line is removed from the menu:

```
function! NERDTreeMenuToggle()
    if &ft == "nerdtree"
        nnoremenu 1.120 PopUp.Add\ To\ Path :call NERDTreeAddNodeToPath()<CR>
    else
        silent! nunmenu PopUp.Add\ To\ Path
    endif
endfunction
```

Note that `nunmenu` must be called silently to suppress errors if the menu item doesn't exist. Next we must set this function to be called on the `MenuPopup` event (i.e. just before the menu is displaued).

```
au! MenuPopup * :call NERDTreeMenuToggle()
```

That seems to do the trick (although I am not a regular user of NERDTree, so I may be missing some subtleties.

Another approach would be to add the line to menu in a new filetype plugin (just put the `nnoremenu` line in a file called nerdtree.vim in $VIM/vimfiles/ftplugin) but this still leaves the problem of removing the line for non-NERDTree buffers, so I think my solution above is slightly cleaner.